# replace using bash - Dynamic value

Tags: json, unix, sed, text-processing

I have a Json file that has following values

```
cat file
    {
    "key1": "value1"
    "key2": "value2",
    }
```

I would like to change value1 and value2. Values are dynamic it changes overtime. My sed should work with any value and mylook up should be by key.
"
my sed command is not helping.

```
 sed -i 's/*\"key2\":*/\"key2\": "someothervalue2"/' file
```

Comment: you don't have any `:` in your input. Update your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using a proper json-parser instead of `sed`, e.g. `jq`.

*infile*

```json
{
  "key1" : "value1",
  "key2" : "value2"
}
```

You can replace its values like this:

```
jq '.key1 = "foo" | .key2 = "bar"' < infile
```

Output:

```json
{
  "key1": "foo",
  "key2": "bar"
}
```

Comment: `jq` is not bash, this is not actually a valid answer

Comment: @user5359531: What about `sed` then, or `awk`?  Are they valid answers?

Comment: `sed` was included in the question

Comment: @user5359531: True, but I still beg to differ.  As I specified in my answer, `sed` does no parsing and hence is error-prone when dealing with e.g. json data.  It seems the OP agrees with me, as this is the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try with awk solution too once.

```
awk '$1 ~ /key[12]/{match($0,/^ +/);printf substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH);sub(/value[0-9]+/,"someothervalue2",$3);printf("%s%s",$0,RS);next} 1'  Input_file
```

**OR**

```
awk '
$1 ~ /key[12]/{
  match($0,/^ +/);
  printf substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH);
  sub(/value[0-9]+/,"someothervalue2",$3);
  printf("%s%s",$0,RS);
  next
}
1
'  Input_file
```

Output will be as follows:

```
     {
     "key1" = "someothervalue2"
     "key2" = "someothervalue2",
     }
```

If you have more than key1 and key2 into your Input_file then change key[12] to key[0-9]+ and let us know how it goes then.

Answer (score 0):

You seem a bit unfamiliar with regex, there are a few problems in your expression. E.g. to match any character you use `.` and then add the star (`.*`) to match it 0 or more times. You should take some time to get familiar with regex as it will save you time and trouble in the future.

But to achieve the desired outcome i used this command:

```
sed -i -r 's/("key2" ?= ?).*,?/\1"someothervalue2",/' file
```

You should put this into a script if you are going to do this a lot so you could just type `./myScript key new_value file`